# Remove submit button in WP Gravity forms plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

How to remove submit button in Wordpress Gravity Form Plugin?

I'd like to insert custom HTML which contain one field and one button inlined and get rid of default button.

The example of the form is on http://fundersandfounders.com "Sign up for VIP tickets"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "form settings" (the very top option in your Form Builder) click 'edit'.

Under "Advanced" tab select "Form Button: Image"

Enter the url of your button image.

Then when you create your shortcode deselect "Display form title" and "Display form description".

Your shortcode will look like this:

```
[gravityform id="X" name="X" title="false" description="false"]
```

Replace "id" and "name" with your form information.

Comment: @Noah How does the above allow for custom HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms offers the ability to have a custom button and markup surrounding it using the filter `gform_submit_button`.

Example:

```
// filter the Gravity Forms button type
add_filter( 'gform_submit_button', 'form_submit_button', 10, 2 );
function form_submit_button( $button, $form ) {
    return "<button class='button' id='gform_submit_button_{$form['id']}'><span>Submit</span></button>";
}
```

More information is available through Gravity Forms, including other examples as per their documentation here: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_submit_button/